# EventPattern on AWS::Event::Rule needed to trigger bash script logger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

We are creating a cron job to be run every 5 minutes that simply logs "hello world" to our Log Groups. This is done with AWS Cloudformation with a task that just echo "hello world".

This is the scheduled rule

```
ScheduledRule: 
Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
Properties: 
  Description: "ScheduledRule"
  ScheduleExpression: "rate(5 minutes)"
  State: "ENABLED"
  Targets: 
    - 
      RoleArn:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ RoleNeeded, Arn ]
      Id: Cluster-Test-Cron-job
      Arn: 
        Ref: ArnOfOurClusterTheScriptShouldExecute
      EcsParameters: 
        TaskDefinitionArn: 
          Ref: TaskDefinitionThatExecutesLoggerScript
        TaskCount: 1
```

Cloudwatch metrics shows that the task was triggered but also indicates `FailedInvocation`. It seemed that we are missing something here, should the `ScheduleExpression` be enough making the script execute every 5 minutes? We check the role needed and it is already the suggested and recommended role to be used with policy `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceEventsRole`, `ArnOfOurClusterTheScriptShouldExecute` and `TaskDefinitionThatExecutesLoggerScript` also works since we tested running the Task with the `TaskDefinitionThatExecutesLoggerScript` setup manually and it logs to our Log Groups.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527163/aws-ecs-create-scheduled-tasks-cron-via-cloudformation) but this also adds to FailedInvocation metric.

What did we miss with the above setup for us to allow the scripts to be executed properly?

Answer (score 0):

We were looking in the wrong direction assuming that we needed an event pattern. But it was the role that has the issue.

**Role Setup with Error**

```
RoleWeNeed:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  Path: /
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument: |
    {
        "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "Service": [ "ecs.amazonaws.com" ]},
            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
        }]
    }
  ManagedPolicyArns:
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceEventsRole
```

We tried manually changing the scheduled rule after it was created via cloudformation and noticed that the role we created with the above setup, although has the correct policies, is not available in the drop down options of roles.

Policy below allow provides policy appropriately but that isn't happening because in the first place, it isn't visible for use of our Event Rule.

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceEventsRole
```

**The wrong setup**

```
AssumeRolePolicyDocument: |
    {
        "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "Service": [ "ecs.amazonaws.com" ]},
            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
        }]
    }
```

The *ecs.amazonaws.com* based on the docs won't make the role available for *Events* which the scheduled rule belongs.

> In IAM roles, use the Principal element in the role's trust policy to specify who can assume the role.

**The correct Setup**

Allow the role to be available for access by the Events with **events.amazonaws.com**

```
AssumeRolePolicyDocument: |
    {
        "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "Service": [ "events.amazonaws.com" ]},
            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
        }]
    }
```